# Erro em função para barra de carregamento utilizando um while(){}

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou tentando montar uma barra de carregamento que se inicia após 2 segundos do carregamento do `document`, Ela a cada `100` milésimos de segundo ganha `1%` de `width`. Porém, quando a página carrega, o console.log() mostra que a função está sendo executada, porém, nada acontece. Como posso corrigir o problema ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var count = 0;
        while(count < 100){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#loader-progress").css({"width":count + "%"})
            },500)
            count++;
        }
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: voce pode usar `debugger;`, dentro do seu while, abrir o seu DevTools do browser e ver o pq esta travando. =)

Comment: mas ele trava a página, não permitindo abrir o devTools

Comment: deixa o devTolls aberto, antes de chamar a pagina =)

Comment: tenta colocar o count++ logo abaixo do while e multiplicar o 100 do timeout pelo count (100*count), acho que vai funcionar...

Comment: coloquei o count++ abaixo do while e parou de travar, mas ainda não aparecem erros, pergunta editada :D

Comment: tentei multiplicar o count no timeout mas não funcionou

Comment: E como está o CSS do seu loader-progress? Se voce aumentar o width manual, ele está aumentando?

Comment: manualmente funciona

Comment: @MuriloGambôa o que você tem que multiplicar é o delay do timeout, nesse seu caso ficaria 500*count: `setTimeout(function(){
                $("#loader-progress").css({"width":count + "%"})
            },500*count)`

Comment: sim @JuniorNunes, eu entendi, porém, não rodou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada chamada desse trecho de código:

```
setTimeout(function(){

       $("#loader-progress").css({"width":count + "%"})
       count++;
},100)
```

terá o valor de `count` definido como zero. Ou seja, você entrou em um loop infinito, pois `count` nunca será incrementado no contexto correto.

Para corrigir seu código, troquei seu `setTimeout` de dentro por um `setInterval`, que chamará a função repetidamente, no seguinte exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
            var count = 0;
            var idIntervalo =  setInterval(function(){
                            if(count == 105){ clearInterval(idIntervalo); }
                            $("#loader-progress").css("width", count + "%");
                            count++;
            }, 100);
    },2000);
});
```

O `idIntervalo` é necessário, pois é a única maneira de parar as chamadas quando se chega ao objetivo, usando o método `clearInterval`.

Você pode conferir um exemplo funcional no link abaixo

https://jsfiddle.net/1j1tf3ny/1/

Comment: como fazer usando um while ?

Comment: Você realmente precisa que seja feito com `while` e `setTimeout`?

Comment: sim :3 por mim eu faria com o if mesmo, mas é que to treinando com while por estar meio fraco nesse ponto

Answer (score 1):

Bom, após um tempo tentando, consegui resolver o problema, marquei a resposta do @ArturTrapp como a certa, pois ela me deu a direção correta para solucionar o problema.

Bom, o código foi reformulado para

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var count = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            while(count !== 100.5){
                $("#loader-progress").css({"width":count + "%"})
                count = count + 0.5;
            }
        },10);
    },2000);
});
```

Porém, ocorre um problema, ele joga do `$("#loader-progress")` de `0%` para `100%` logo no primeiro `loop`.
Mas, apenas substituindo `while`, por `if`, o mesmo funciona perfeitamente no `timer` colocado, ficando então:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var count = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            if(count !== 100.5){
                $("#loader-progress").css({"width":count + "%"})
                count = count + 0.5;
            }
        },10);
    },2000);
});
```

- Foi colocado um `count !== 100.5` como condição, pois se colocado à `100`, o mesmo daria um `width` máximo de `99.5%` no `$("#loader-progress")` já que o `counter` precisaria ser diferente de `100` para que o `if` fosse executado